# Remove iTunes and QuickTime Player from macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: macos, mojave

Simply do not need these. Is there a way to remove them from my machine?
`sudo rm -rf QuickTime\ Player.app/` didnt work :/

MacOS version `10.14.5 (18F132)`

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)

**Edit:**

Error on running `sudo rm -rf QuickTime\ Player.app/` (trimmed down)

```
rm: QuickTime Player.app//Contents/XPCServices: Operation not permitted
rm: QuickTime Player.app//Contents/Info.plist: Operation not permitted
rm: QuickTime Player.app//Contents/PkgInfo: Operation not permitted
rm: QuickTime Player.app//Contents/version.plist: Operation not permitted
rm: QuickTime Player.app//Contents: Operation not permitted
rm: QuickTime Player.app/: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: What happened when you ran `sudo rm -rf QuickTime\ Player.app/`? Did it work for iTunes. Quicktime is said to be a dependency for other programs so I don't recommend deleting it. Itunes, however, should pose little risk. Note that iTunes will be removed this fall with the new Catalina operating system.

Comment: Updated the question. Didnt run on itunes. Lemme try

Comment: Apparently nothing is permitted.

Comment: Try running again with super user enabled https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012 . This could break your operating system. I don't know because I haven't done it before.

Comment: @www139 - enabling root [not good anyway] won't get you round SIP restrictions.